# platform plugin libqxcb.so found but can not find Qt libs. (Deploying Qt application for Linux with Dynamic linking)

Tags: linux, qt

I am trying to deploy a Qt5 application for Linux (Debian) with dynamic linking. My app runs well on Ubuntu where all dependencies work well. My application package looks like this:

```
 - application.exe
 - qt.conf
 - libicudata.so.54
 - libicui18n.so.54
 - libicuuc.so.54
 - libQt5Core.so.5
 - libQt5DBus.so.5
 - libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
 - libQt5Gui.so.5
 - libQt5Widgets.so.5
 - platforms / libqxcb.so
```

When I run it from the terminal on Debian I get this error message:

> This application failed to start because it could not find 
>   or load   the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Available platform plugins are: xcb.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>   Aborted

Then I ran ldd on libqxcb.so and saw that it I could not find the qt libs in the main folder. My application.exe can find all the qt libs by rpath in pro file so it is only the platform plugin that can not find the qt libs.

How can I set the path to Qt libs for the platform plugins?

Comment: What command do you run from the terminal ?

Comment: I ran ./application command when I got the error message. And ran the ldd ./application and saw that it could find the qt libs. And ldd ./libqxcb.so and saw that it could not find the qt libs but depends on them, maybe that's not the problem?

Comment: If you add the folder with Qt libs to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, will the application start?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, both on Ubuntu and Debian, when running a Python application that relies on `PyQt5` for its GUI:

```sh
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
even though it was found. This application failed to start because
no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the
application may fix this problem.
```

I got it easily fixed on Ubuntu. The fix on Debian was much harder. Below are my solutions.

> ***DISCLAIMER***
> *I'm not an experienced Linux user. Forgive me if the 'solutions' are more or less stitched together with duct tape.*

#### 1. Ubuntu

On Ubuntu, I had it fixed quickly with this solution:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0
```

#### 2. Debian

On Debian, it took me quite some time to find a fix. I first tried several things I found on this page:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without

like:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libxcb-util1
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5x11extras5
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5dbus5
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5widgets5
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5network5
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5gui5
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libqt5core5a
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libdouble-conversion1
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libxcb-xinerama0
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install '^libxcb.*-dev'
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install '^libxcb-util.*-dev'
```

Nothing helped. I was wondering: could this have something to do with the fact that I was deploying a `Python3.9` venv on my Debian machine? On Ubuntu, I was working in the native `Python3.8`, so I guess all installations and re-installations worked just fine. But with a virtual environment, it might be not so straightforward?

*My theory: I believe the virtual environment has its own Qt5 libs stored somewhere, and all the installations and reinstallations are happening on the "native" Qt5 libs - different from the Qt5 libs in the virtual environment.*

Anyhow, I finally tried this:

```sh
$ ldd ~/Python-3.9.2/py3.9.2-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so | grep "not found"

    libxcb-util.so.1 => not found
    libxcb-util.so.1 => not found
```

This command figures out the missing dependencies for the given `.so` file. I then downloaded `libxcb-util.so.1` and `libxcb-util.so.1.0.0` from this webpage:

https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Astevenpusser%3Alibxcb-util1&package=libxcb-util1

which I found on this forum:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=135672

I added both `libxcb-util.so.1` and `libxcb-util.so.1.0.0` to the `~/Python-3.9.2/py3.9.2-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/` folder and then added this folder to my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/johan/Python-3.9.2/py3.9.2-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Finally, the python application works!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by starting the application with a startup script from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html. But if anyone have any idea on how to solve it without using a script I would like to hear how. On the qt doc, same link as above, it says that it should be possible to do it with just rpath.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was trying to deploy my QT app as well. Try to find the `plugins/platforms` folder in your Qt installation. For me it was `..Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/platforms`.

Copying the `platforms` folder to the folder where my .so is stored worked for me. Oh! and don't forget to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/folder_With_.so_and_Platform`

Answer (score 0):

on debian:
`pip install pyqt5==5.15.2`
works for now